# Redirect old urls to archive page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I need to **301 redirect** some old urls to the category archive page.

Here's an example of the old url structure that need to be redirected:

- *domain.com/vetrina/name-post-1*
- *domain.com/vetrina/name-post-2*
- *domain.com/vetrina/name-post-3*
- *etc.*

Since those pages **don't exist anymore** I simply need to redirect them to the archive page of the category:

- *domain.com/category/vetrina*

What is the correct way to do that in the .htaccess file?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RedirectMatch directive

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/vetrina/.+$ http://example.com/category/vetrina
```